# Why won't my form display?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 with a Bootswatch theme. Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.1.1/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbarcollapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LicenseApp</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nav 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="">Username</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input class="form-control" name="username" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas why I'm having so many problems? Am I missing a DIV or something?

Comment: Can you see the form if you view the source?

Comment: Yeah shows up in view source but I only get the nav on the page

Comment: So that'd mean it's a CSS issue, right? HTML is being generated.

Comment: Thing is, I'm using the CSS from CDN... So surely it would be right?

Comment: there is no fullfinished, issue-free css...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is placed under your navbar because your navbar is fixed at top.

With following css rules:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
   top: 0;
   border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
```

Therefore, either push your form more down or make navbar not fixed, for example remove `navbar-fixed-top` from this element:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

Therefore, it displays **[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nr6k5/1/)**

Or as @Jamesking56 noticed, changing `navbar-fixed-top` to `navbar-static-top` works

Comment: How would I go about pushing my form down?

Comment: @Jamesking56 Like I said, make navbar not fixed (which pushes form down) or push your form down using for example margin-top or similar, it is up to you what you want to do. But the answer to your initial question is that your form is there, it was just behind the navbar ;)

Comment: Ah! I wanted `navbar-static-top` not `navbar-fixed-top`

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap, when using a fixed navigation header, you usually put a padding-top on the body, the same height as the header.

See here: [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)

> Body padding required
>
> The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the body. Try out your own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.
>
> body { padding-top: 70px; }
>
> Make sure to include this after the core Bootstrap CSS.